# Migrate customers from Magento to Woocommerce

Tags: mysql, magento, woocommerce

I'm in the process of moving a Magento store into WooCommerce. The problem is that Magento and WordPress have different password authentication algorithms.

The way Magento stores the password: `md5($salt.$password).':'.$salt;`

The way WordPress stores the password: `md5($password)`

Is there a way to export existing Magento customers into WordPress and keep their passwords?

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't.  As you noted, Magento stores its passwords with a salt

```
password:salt
```

Wordpress also stores its passwords with a salt — except the salt is an empty string and the same for everyone (i.e. Wordpress doesn't use a salt).

The is a security feature of Magento's hashing, and is meant to stop exactly the sort of thing you're trying to do.

In theory you could generate a [rainbow hash table](https://www.google.com/search?q=rainbow+hash+table) for each of the unique salts in the database, use this to crack your users passwords, and recreate them in Wordpress with a salt-less  hashing. However, that's a non-trivial task if you're not familiar with the implementation of hashing algorithms, and would also take a significant amount of time.

The usual approach to this is to create new accounts in the new system, and then automatically email users a password reset link the first time they attempt to login (with additional messaging explaining things)

You could also look into changing Wordpress's login functionality — but that sounds like a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this WordPress plugin. It allows to migrate customer passwords to WooCommerce. After finished the migration, just contact them and they will send you an additional plugin that allows your customers log in using their old passwords.

**Plugin link:** https://wordpress.org/plugins/nextcart-woocommerce-migration/

Tt works like a charm!